# iPad Projector Portrait Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, projector

I want to present an iPad game which is only playable in portrait mode by using a projector. I don't have a VGA Adapter so I cannot try it out (but university does, so on presentation day I will have one). So my question is: Is it possible to have the projector showing the iPad in Portrait Mode?
Thanks, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will mimic the iPad current orientation, so if your orientation is portrait then the projector will show it portrait.

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: @DanielRichter you should consider accepting the answer if it was helpful :)